# Location information (store/send over network)

Tags: java, android, converting, geospatial

I have to calculate a user's location periodically and store & send it over the network on Android. I also have to indicate errors during calculation of location as well. The errors could come from the location API or user having disabled their GPS. I have written the following class for this purpose:

```
/**
 * Store info about a location and make it available in various formats.
 * 
 * @author deepankar
 */
public class LocationInfo {

    /* Labels for keys when converting to key-value pairs */
    private static final String KEY_STATUS_CODE = "status_code";
    private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
    private static final String KEY_PROVIDER = "provider";
    private static final String KEY_ALTITUDE = "altitude";
    private static final String KEY_TRAVELSPEED = "travelspeed";
    private static final String KEY_ACCURACY = "accuracy";
    private static final String KEY_LONGTITUDE = "longitude";
    private static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    private static final String KEY_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

    /**
     * The unique id for this location.
     */
    private int mId;

    /**
     * The time of capture of this location as reported by location API. In
     * milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.0 UTC.
     */
    private String mTimeStamp = "0";
    /**
     * The latitude.
     */
    private String mLat = "0.0";
    /**
     * The longitude.
     */
    private String mLong = "0.0";
    /**
     * The accuracy of measurement, in meters.
     */
    private String mAcc = "0.0";
    /**
     * The travelspeed in m/s.
     */
    private String mTravelSpeed = "0.0";
    /**
     * The altitude in meters.
     */
    private String mAltitude = "0.0";
    /**
     * The location provider API name.
     */
    private String mProvider = "fused";
    /**
     * The status of the location info. This is used to indicate errors from API
     * calls or GPS settings. "OK" if the location is valid.
     */
    private String mStatus = "CATFOREST";
    /**
     * Code corresponding to the error indicated by status.
     */
    private String mStatusCode = "-1";
    /**
     * Whether this location was sent to the server.
     */
    private String mSent = "false";

    /**
     * @param id
     *            The unique id for this location.
     * @return The LocationInfo
     */
    public LocationInfo id(int id) {
        this.mId = id;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @param time
     *            The time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.0 UTC.
     * @return The LocationInfo
     */
    public LocationInfo timestamp(long time) {
        this.mTimeStamp = String.valueOf(time);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @param lat
     *            The latitude of this location.
     * @return The LocationInfo
     */
    public LocationInfo lat(double lat) {
        this.mLat = String.valueOf(lat);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @param lat
     *            The longitude of this location.
     * @return The LocationInfo
     */
    public LocationInfo lng(double lng) {
        this.mLong = String.valueOf(lng);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @param acc
     *            The accuracy of measurement, in meters.
     * @return The LocationInfo
     */
    public LocationInfo acc(double acc) {
        this.mAcc = String.valueOf(acc);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @param provider
     *            The location provider API name.
     * @return The LocationInfo
     */
    public LocationInfo provider(String provider) {
        this.mProvider = provider;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param status
     *            The status of the location info. This is used to indicate
     *            errors from API calls or GPS settings. "OK" if the location is
     *            valid.
     * @return The LocationInfo
     */
    public LocationInfo status(String status) {
        this.mStatus = status;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param statusCode
     *            Code corresponding to the error indicated by status.
     * @return The LocationInfo
     */
    public LocationInfo statusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.mStatusCode = String.valueOf(statusCode);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param travelSpeed
     *            The travelspeed in m/s.
     * @return The LocationInfo
     */
    public LocationInfo travelSpeed(double travelSpeed) {
        this.mTravelSpeed = String.valueOf(travelSpeed);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param altitude
     *            The altitude in meters.
     * @return The LocationInfo
     */
    public LocationInfo altitude(double altitude) {
        this.mAltitude = String.valueOf(altitude);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Marks this location info as stored in db.
     * 
     * @return The LocationInfo
     */
    public LocationInfo sent() {
        this.mSent = "true";
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Get this LocationInfo as a ContentValues key-value set.
     * 
     * @return LocationInfo as ContentValues key-value set.
     */

    public ContentValues toDbRow() {
        ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
        row.put(LocInfoTable.COL_TIMESTAMP, mTimeStamp);
        row.put(LocInfoTable.COL_LATITUDE, mLat);
        row.put(LocInfoTable.COL_LONGITUDE, mLong);
        row.put(LocInfoTable.COL_ACCURACY, mAcc);
        row.put(LocInfoTable.COL_PROVIDER, mProvider);
        row.put(LocInfoTable.COL_STATUS, mStatus);
        row.put(LocInfoTable.COL_STATUS_CODE, mStatusCode);
        row.put(LocInfoTable.COL_SENT_TO_CT, mSent);
        return row;
    }

    /**
     * Get this LocationInfo as a JSON Object.
     * 
     * @return LocationInfo as JSON.
     */
    public JSONObject toJSON() {
        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
        try {
            message.put(KEY_ID, this.mId);
            message.put(KEY_TIMESTAMP, this.mTimeStamp);
            message.put(KEY_LATITUDE, this.mLat);
            message.put(KEY_LONGTITUDE, this.mLong);
            message.put(KEY_ACCURACY, this.mAcc);
            message.put(KEY_PROVIDER, this.mProvider);
            message.put(KEY_STATUS, this.mStatus);
            message.put(KEY_STATUS_CODE, this.mStatusCode);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Logger.error("Error while converting location info to JSON");
        }
        return message;
    }

    /**
     * Get this LocationInfo as a Hashtable.
     * 
     * @return LocationInfo as Hashtable.
     */
    public Hashtable<String, String> toHashtable() {
        Hashtable<String, String> table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        table.put(KEY_ID, String.valueOf(this.mId));
        table.put(KEY_TIMESTAMP, this.mTimeStamp);
        table.put(KEY_LATITUDE, this.mLat);
        table.put(KEY_LONGTITUDE, this.mLong);
        table.put(KEY_ACCURACY, this.mAcc);
        table.put(KEY_TRAVELSPEED, this.mTravelSpeed);
        table.put(KEY_ALTITUDE, this.mAltitude);
        table.put(KEY_PROVIDER, this.mProvider);
        table.put(KEY_STATUS, this.mStatus);
        table.put(KEY_STATUS_CODE, this.mStatusCode);
        return table;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Long.valueOf(mTimeStamp);
        return "Lat: " + mLat + ", Long: " + mLong + ", Acc: " + mAcc
                + ", Time: " + mTimeStamp;
    }

}
```

- Am I using the correct pattern to store multiple fields for my purpose?
- What can I improve in my code style?
- What other improvements do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using strings to store numbers and booleans, bad idea™. Store them as the type they need to be and only convert when needed (JSON allows floating point and boolean values without the explicit conversion to string)
2. I'm not a fan of hungarian notation. The `m` prefix is unnecessary and just adds clutter to the names. A good ide will allow you to highlight field differently from local variables.
3. You should add getters for the properties.
4. You have 2 different key-to-field mappings. I suggest that there should only be one of them.
5. You can convert to 3 different objects I suggest that there should also be a way to get a LocationInfo object from one of those (and make sure the round-trip is valid).
6. add `equals` and `hashcode`